# Finding p for trend in R - testing the trend across an ordinal categorical variable

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, trend

How do I calculate $p$ for a trend in `R`? My predictor variable is an ordered categorical variable with 4 categories and my outcome is dichotomous. (I am also using survey data so I want to use the weights, and survey design).

Model:

```
mod <- svyglm(outcome ~ predictor + cov1 + cov2, design = svydsgn, family = quasipoisson())
```

For the result, I am getting answers for each category of the predictor such as:

```
Cat B: 2.35 (1.5 - 3.5), P<0.001
Cat C: 3.50 (2.7 - 4.5), p<0.00002 etc. (Category A is the reference category).
```

How do I test the trend across the three categories of my predictor? My predictor variable is already defined.

Comment: How are you defining 'trend'?

Comment: @Glen_b - just wanted to see if the observed pattern was significant (moving from one category to the next). I got the answer, eventually.

Comment: If you're deciding what to test for *after* you see the data, your p-values don't mean what you want them to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to transform your factor predictor to an ordered factor by, e.g.

```
mydata$ord_predictor <- ordered(mydata$predictor)
```

Then in the output of your model, you should see, among other things, coefficients named: `ord_predictor.L`, `ord_predictor.Q`, `ord_predictor.C` along with the associated estimates and p-values.

Here, `ord_predictor.L` refers to the linear trend. If it has a significant estimate, it means there is a linear trend in the estimated relation.  By the same token, `ord_predictor.Q` tells you if there is a quadratic trend, `ord_predictor.C` relates to the cubic trend ad so on.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! You just saved an entire dissertation.